# Jquery Ajax and asp.net WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I'm trying to call a webmethod in an aspx page using jquery ajax. The ajax code is callind the page but I can't go into the method although the Page_Load is been accesed after the ajax Post request. I've tried in many ways but I can't.

I hope you can help me, I'm going crazy.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string nombre = Request.QueryString["nombre"];
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.CargarDatosIniciales();                  
        }
    }

    [WebMethod(enableSession:true)]
    [ScriptMethod()]
    public static void GuardarDatosFamilia(string nombre, string tipoDoc)
    {
        string nombrePersona = nombre;
        string tipoDocumento = tipoDoc;
    }


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FRM_Caracterizacion.aspx/GuardarDatosFamilia", //Direccion del servicio web segido de /Nombre del metodo a llamar
        beforeSend: function () { alert('I am sending'); },
        data: "{'nombre':'"+ nombre+"','tipoDoc':'"+ tipoDoc"'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json" 
        });
```

UPDATE:

This is what I get in Firebug:

```
     POST http://localhost:51620/FRM_Caracterizacion.aspx/GuardarDatosFamilia 200 OK    3.22s

     Parámetros application/x-www-form-urlencoded
     nombre Jhon Fredy
     tipoDoc    1
     Fuente
     nombre=Jhon+Fredy&tipoDoc=1
```

UPDATE 2:

SOLUTION

What I've done for my specific problem was:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FRM_Caracterizacion.aspx", //Direccion del servicio web segido de /Nombre del metodo a llamar
        beforeSend: function () { alert('I am sending'); },
        data: { metodo: 'AgregarDatosFamilia',
        nombre:nombre,
        tipoDoc:tipoDoc
        },
        dataType: "json" //Esto quiere decir que los datos nos llegaran como un objeto json
    });


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Form["metodo"] == "AgregarDatosFamilia")
            {
                this.GuardarDatosFamilia();
            }
            this.CargarDatosIniciales();                  
        }
    }

    public void GuardarDatosFamilia()
    {
        string nombre = Request.Form["nombre"].ToString(),
        string tipoDoc = Request.Form["tipoDoc"].ToString()
    }
```

Thanks everybody, I appreciate suggestions!

Comment: Do you have Fiddler installed? it will show you whats going across the wire and any expception text the .NET runtime might have thrown before your webmethod hit

Comment: what are you trying to do? you are not returning anything from the web service, and nothing doing after the ajax call succeeded.

Comment: What are you getting as response, 500 internal server error?

Comment: Hi, sorry if i wasn't so clear. I don't speak english very well. Actually I have debuged using Firebug and visual studio breakpoints. After the ajax call to the method, it goes to the aspx page and execute the pageload, it doesn't show any exception but It doesn't go into the method. Am I being clear? Sorry by my english.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you are properly calling this on client side

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "FRM_Caracterizacion.aspx/GuardarDatosFamilia", //Direccion del servicio web segido de /Nombre del metodo a llamar
        beforeSend: function () { alert('I am sending'); },
        data: "{'nombre':'"+ nombre+"','tipoDoc':'"+ tipoDoc"'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json" 
        });
```

then in the browser hit F12 and watch the traffic - you will see that the webmethod is being called , you are not returning anything though ,

```
[WebMethod(enableSession:true)]
[ScriptMethod()]  //this can't be void - change to String
public static String GuardarDatosFamilia(string nombre, string tipoDoc)
{
    string nombrePersona = nombre;
    string tipoDocumento = tipoDoc;
    return "successful ajax";
}
```

try that to test - also if you were trying to access string nombre that was declared in Page_Load - that is not possible in a Static Method , the only data you will have access to is what was passed into webmethod

I put a comment saying to change it from void - it actually can be void - but that is if you want to perform some action , usually with a database - even then its good practice to return a string to let the client know if it was a success or not

Comment: I donn't know what's wrong, It seems to be calling the aspx page correctly, I got a question, If i set a breakpoint into the webmethod it must be arranged at debugging time?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I have a similar issue as @jisazat. In my case, it won't break into the method, instead returning the full page markup. Do I need a special configuration setting to enable ASP.NET to use those attributes, or...?

Answer (score 1):

create a different webservice for webmethod,, Read more [Consuming-Webservice-using-JQuery-ASP-NET-Applicat](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66432/Consuming-Webservice-using-JQuery-ASP-NET-Applicat)
 and [calling webservice](http://forums.asp.net/t/1745531.aspx/1)

Comment: I put webmethods in aspx pages all the time

Comment: he doesn't want to call a webservice - he wants to call a webmethod in an aspx page